# How to find number of Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays of the previous month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The problem is getting the number of Fridays, Saturdays, and Sundays in the previous month, I can't get to the ideal solution.

I defined the last month as

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)  AS start_date,
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1) AS last_date
```

```
(DATEDIFF(WK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 3, -1)) * 2) 
      - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as P
```

I tried to find weekend days, but it absolutely does not meet my needs.

Comment: Just use a calendar table, then the solution is trivial.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: The OP has tagged [[tag:sql-server]], @Mureinik .

Comment: Yikes, missed that somehow. How embarrassing.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this and many more date related problems is to create a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a table with precalculated dates for eg 10-20 years along with any extra reporting columns you may need like Year, Month, Quarter, Week number, day of week, Weekend and holiday flags, reporting periods etc. This way it's easy to find how many weekend days are in the last month, or between two business events

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I can only query this database.

Comment: You could build your calendar table on the fly, such as by using `GENERATE_SERIES`. Though I strongly suggest you talk to someone that *can* amend the database, and they build a calendar table; they are an **invaluable** tool.

Comment: You should be able to embed a CTE with three columns - the starting day of the previous month (7 values) x number of days in the month (4 values) and containing the number of days you're looking for as the final column. You can compute those 28 rows once and just use that, rather than doing any date maths and if you're sure you cannot be sold on a permanent calendar table.

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, YourDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in the comments, the *simplest* way is to just use your Calendar table. Presumably you have one, and if you don't then create one; they are an *invaluable* tool. Then the solution is as simple as getting a `COUNT` from that table:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.DimDate DD
WHERE DD.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE()))
  AND DD.Date < DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE())
  AND DD.[DayName] IN ('Friday','Saturday','Sunday'); --This is a specific column in the table, so not language specific.
```

If you don't have a calendar table, and can't (I doubt this, you likely just need to talk to someone that can), you can build such a dataset on the fly. One method would be with `GENERATE_SERIES`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE())),DATEADD(DAY, -1,DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE()))))V(StartDate,EndDate)
     CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0,DATEDIFF(DAY,V.StartDate,EndDate)) GS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(DAY,GS.value,V.StartDate))) C(CalendarDate)
WHERE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.CalendarDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 IN (6,0,1); --6 = Friday, 0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, regardless of language/DATEFIRST setting
```

If you aren't on 2022+, you'll need to use a Tally instead to get the dates:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))V(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2), --more cross joins, more rows
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I-1,  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0)) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Calendar C
WHERE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.CalendarDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 IN (6,0,1); --6 = Friday, 0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, regardless of language/DATEFIRST setting;
```

Answer (score -2):

On ***siggemannen*** suggestion, using **sys.objects**:

```
WITH PreviousMonthDates AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, number, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) AS DateInPreviousMonth
    FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 AS number
         FROM sys.objects) AS Numbers
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, number, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
        AND DATEADD(DAY, number, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) <= EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
)
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateInPreviousMonth) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS Fridays,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateInPreviousMonth) = 7 THEN 1 END) AS Saturdays,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DateInPreviousMonth) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Sundays
FROM
    PreviousMonthDates;
```

Comment: Watch out cause DATENAME is non-deterministic and might not be in english. Also, `master.dbo.spt_values` isn't always available i think. i usually go for sys.objects